# Time range is invalid statement

Tags: c#

I am trying to create an if statement based on the dropdown created below. That determines whether the Time from is before or after Time To. According to the results, show validation.

For Example: Time From 4:00 and Time To 4:30. Should be acceptable.

However if Time From 4:00 and Time To 3:30. This should not be acceptable.

Any ideas?

```
private void BindTime()
  {
      // Set the start time (00:00 means 12:00 AM)
      DateTime StartTime = DateTime.ParseExact("00:00", "HH:mm", null);
      // Set the end time (23:55 means 11:55 PM)
      DateTime EndTime = DateTime.ParseExact("23:55", "HH:mm", null);
      //Set 15 minutes interval
      TimeSpan Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0);
      //To set 1 hour interval
      //TimeSpan Interval = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0);           
      ddlTimeFrom.Items.Clear();
      ddlTimeTo.Items.Clear();
      while (StartTime <= EndTime)
      {
          ddlTimeFrom.Items.Add(StartTime.ToShortTimeString());
          ddlTimeTo.Items.Add(StartTime.ToShortTimeString());
          StartTime = StartTime.Add(Interval);
      }
      ddlTimeFrom.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("  Select  ", "0"));
      ddlTimeTo.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("  Select  ", "0"));
  }
```

Comment: convert the time in secons and subtract them. then you have the difference. depending on what minus what, you can decide

Comment: In your while loop, it should be ddlTimeTo.Items.Add(EndTime.ToShortTimeString());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to validate, use this function:

```
private bool IsSelectionValid()
{
    DateTime fromTime;
    DateTime toTime;

    if(!DateTime.TryParse(ddlTimeFrom.SelectedValue, out fromTime) ||
       !DateTime.TryParse(ddlTimeTo.SelectedValue, out toTime))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return fromTime < toTime;
}
```

`IsSelectionValid` would give return false if fromTime is not less than toTime.